# Copy file with dynamic name in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I have a business scenario where a unix user ftp files to unix box in the following format 'BusinessData_date.dat' Please note that date part is dynamic and hence keeps on changing daily. e.g 'BusinessData_20131210.dat'

How can i run copy command to copy the file to a different directory daily and also archive the previous day file so that it does not read twice.

Trying out the following...getting an error

```
$ cp -pr /Tickets/data/BusinessData_"$(date+%Y%m%d)".dat /sftpdata/dataloader/data/BusinessData_"$(date+%Y%m%d)".csv
```

Comment: show us detail on how to archive the previous day file ?

Answer (score 1):

You need a space to split the actual command & the arguments. Also you dont need the quotes.

```
cp -pr ..../BusinessData_$(date +%Y%m%d).dat ..../BusinessData_$(date +%Y%m%d).csv
```

Comment: Tried the using the suggested syntax but getting error as -bash: date+%Y%m%d: command not found

Comment: @Trideep There is a space between date and %Y. The command looks like: `date<space>+%Y..`.

Answer (score 0):

```
cp -p /Tickets/data/BusinessData_"$(date +%Y%m%d)".dat /sftpdata/dataloader/data/BusinessData_"$(date +%Y%m%d)".csv
```